# Is this a proper Laravel Passport use case?

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

So think of my application as a CMS (laravel 5.7). I'm slowly adding in more javascript to make it more reactive. So I had the usual validation logic that makes sure the user is logged in and all that. But now when I use Vue to submit a comment payload it looks a little like this:

So looking at this, anyone could just change/mock the this.user.id to any number, I would like to also send a login token with the payload which then gets validated in the backend once the server receives the post request.

In the backend, ideally I'd want to have some kind of safe guard that it checks whether the api_token of the user matches with this.user.id to ensure the user.id wasn't mocked on the front end.

I read this portion: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Part of it says:

> This Passport middleware will attach a laravel_token cookie to your outgoing responses. This cookie contains an encrypted JWT that Passport will use to authenticate API requests from your JavaScript application. Now, you may make requests to your application's API without explicitly passing an access token:

But I'm still a bit unsure how that JWT gets generated in the first place. I don't have the vue components for the create token crud added because I want it to be done automatically. I think I'm slightly overthinking this..

Is this a good use case for Laravel Passport? I was looking through the tutorial and right now I don't have a need for custom oauth token creations and all the crud. I just want a unique token to be saved on the user side, that can expire, but also be used to validate requests. Am I on the right track here with Passport or should I use a different approach?

```
postComment(){
axios.post('/api/view/' + this.query.id+'/comment',{
id: this.user.id,
body: this.commentBox
})
.then((response) =>{
//Unshift places data to top of array, shifts everything else down.
this.comments.unshift(response.data);
this.commentBox = '';
document.getElementById("commentBox").value = "";
flash

('Comment posted successfully');
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log(error);
})
},
```

**Update - Reply to Jeff**

Hi! Thanks for your answer. It's not an SPA (might be in the future), but the comment box and the comment section is also integrated with websockets and there's a laravel Echo instance on it.

I guess where I'm feeling uncertain is the security of it.
I pass a user prop with `:user="{{Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->toJson() : 'null'}}"` into the vue component that contains the `postComment()` function.

This is where the `id: this.user.id` comes from. The route is defined in the api.php in a route middleware group for ['api'] like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function(){
Route::post('/view/{query}/comment','CommentController@store');
});
```

In my controller which calls a service to create the comment, the $request

```
public function makejson(createNewCommentRequest $request, Query $query){
$comment = $query->comments()->create([
'body' => $request->get('body'),
])->user()->associate(User::find($request->id));
$id = $comment->id;
$comment->save();
}
```

The createNewCommentRequest is a FormRequest class.

For now the authorize() function just checks whether the request()->id is an int:

```
public function authorize()
{
if(is_int(request()->id)){
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

From within there if I log the request(), all it outputs is:

```
array ( 'id' => 1, 'body' => 'gg', )
```

I thought I would need to add logic to authorize the request based on whether the user token and the request() yield the same user id? I'd want to avoid the scenario where someone can modify the post request and comment using another users id.

In the Network section of devtools, in the Request headers, i see it pushed a laravel_token cookie. I'm assuming that `laravel_token` is what stores the user session? If so, how would one validate based on that token?

I was playing around and added the route:

```
Route::get('/token', function() {
return Auth::user()->createToken('test');
});
```

When I went to it i got the following:

```
{
"accessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImE4NDE2NGVkM2NkODc5NDY3MzAxYzUyNmVkN2MyMGViZTllNzJlMGMzMjRiMmExNWYzZDgwZGNmMzEzMDk1MTRmNTY1NGMxYWUwMTE2ZGRkIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiYTg0MTY0ZWQzY2Q4Nzk0NjczMDFjNTI2ZWQ3YzIwZWJlOWU3MmUwYzMyNGIyYTE1ZjNkODBkY2YzMTMwOTUxNGY1NjU0YzFhZTAxMTZkZGQiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDY1NTQzNDEsIm5iZiI6MTU0NjU1NDM0MSwiZXhwIjoxNTc4MDkwMzQwLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.NMETCBkOrMQGUsXlcas6CvTFJ0xRC8v4AJzC5GtWANdl8YsPBGlyCozMe1OGc8Fnq8GC_GZFkKmMT27umeVcSyaWriZB139kvtWzY6ylZ300vfa5iI-4XC_tJKoyuwDEofqMLDA4nyrtMrp_9YGqPcg6ddR61BLqdvfr0y3Nm5WWkyMqBzjKV-HFyuR0PyPQbnLtQGCzRFUQWbV4XWvH2rDgeI71S6EwmjP7J1aDA2UBVprGqNXdTbxWpSINMkZcgrDvl4hdqNzet-OwB2lu2453R-xKiJkl8ezwEqkURwMj70G-t9NjQGIBInoZ-d3gM2C3J9mEWMB5lyfSMaKzhrsnObgEHcotORw6jWNsDgRUxIipJrSJJ0OLx29LHBjkZWIWIrtsMClCGtLXURBzkP-Oc-O9Xa38m8m6O9z-P8i6craikAIckv9YutmYHIXCAFQN2cAe2mmKp7ds1--HWN_P5qqw6ytuR268_MbexxGDTyq8KzUYRBjtkgVyhuVsS7lDgUHgXvJfHNmdCulpiPhmbtviPfWaZM19likSjKHLTpIn2PpfTflddfhB9Eb4X24wGH7Y5hwxASe7gDs_R707LphS1EH4cTE8p2XW_lLv0jo89ep9IUPUO27pWLsqabt8uTr5OoKQeNZmXT6XiJ9tK3HhRgvIt7DYt8vqlRw",
    "token": {
    "id": "a84164ed3cd879467301c526ed7c20ebe9e72e0c324b2a15f3d80dcf31309514f5654c1ae0116ddd",
    "user_id": 1,
    "client_id": 1,
    "name": "lol",
    "scopes": [],
    "revoked": false,
    "created_at": "2019-01-03 22:25:40",
    "updated_at": "2019-01-03 22:25:40",
    "expires_at": "2020-01-03 22:25:40"
    }
    }
```

Now in Postman, when I send a get request to:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request){return $request->user();});
```

I added a authorization header of type Bearer Token for the string captured in the variable: `accessToken`. In return I get the user, no issue. However where and how is the accessToken generated? It's not saved in the database?

Comment: Maybe [Consuming your API with Javascript](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mozammil Thanks for the comment - I had already referenced that same link / section in my post, but am not sure about how the JWT is generated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Take the user ID that Laravel gives you from the token, rather than sending it from the front end. You can also check the scopes assigned to the token:

```
Route::post('/api/view/{query}/comment', function (Request $request, Query $query) {
    if ($request->user()->tokenCan('comment-on-queries')) {
        $query->comments()->create([
            'body' => $request->get('body'),
            'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
        ]);
    }
});
```

If this isn't a single page app, and only the comment box is handled by ajax, the default Laravel scaffolding should handle this by adding a CSRF token to axios config. In that case you don't need Passport, because the user is stored in the session.  Still though, don't take the user ID from the front end, get it from `\Auth::id()`

Here's the key difference: If they login using PHP, your server has a session stored and knows who is logged in.

If you are creating a single-page app separate from your Laravel app, you have to rely on Passport and tokens to ensure the user has the authority to do what they're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, thanks for your reply! I posted a response in my original question under 'Update - Reply to Jeff'. Very much appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, was overthinking it. Basically didn't need a whole lot to get it working.

- Added the CreateFreshApiToken middleware to the web group in app\Http\Kernel.php.
- The axios responses attach that cookie on the outgoing responses
- The api middleware group had to be 'auth:api'.

The user instance can be then called via request()->user() which is awesome.